# MYSQL, 1:n relation into single row with restriction

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I have those MySQL (simplified) schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE `library` (
  `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `app` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `app` (`app`,`filename`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `app` (`app`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `library_tags` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My goal was to get for each "library" entries every associates "tags". If no tags are associates to library entry, it return NULL in tags's fields.

That works by doing these :

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS library.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT( tags.`id` ORDER BY tags.`id` ASC SEPARATOR ',' ) as `tag_id`,
  GROUP_CONCAT( tags.`tag` ORDER BY tags.`id` ASC SEPARATOR ',' ) as `tag_name`
FROM `library` AS library
LEFT JOIN `library_tags` AS libtags
  ON library.`id` = libtags.`file` 
LEFT JOIN `tags` AS tags
  ON libtags.`tag` = tags.`id` 
WHERE library.`app` = "53bd8997ad2ee"
GROUP BY library.`id` 
ORDER BY  library.`created` DESC
LIMIT 99999 OFFSET 0
```

My next step is to add a restriction that return library's entries based on tags's id, like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS library.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT( tags.`id` ORDER BY tags.`id` ASC SEPARATOR ',' ) as `tag_id`,
  GROUP_CONCAT( tags.`tag` ORDER BY tags.`id` ASC SEPARATOR ',' ) as `tag_name`
FROM `library` AS library
LEFT JOIN `library_tags` AS libtags
  ON library.`id` = libtags.`file` 
LEFT JOIN `tags` AS tags
  ON libtags.`tag` = tags.`id` 
WHERE library.`app` = "53bd8997ad2ee"
  AND  tags.`id` IN (9,14) 
GROUP BY library.`id` 
ORDER BY  library.`created` DESC
LIMIT 99999 OFFSET 0
```

That works too, but GROUP_CONCAT is affected by restriction, and every entries only return selected tags instead on of full tags list per entry.

My question is "how to keep this single query with a full list of tags per entries?"

Additional question is: "does it impact on MySQL performence to do it?"

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Put the library tag restriction in the LEFT JOIN condition..

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS library.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT( tags.`id` ORDER BY tags.`id` ASC SEPARATOR ',' ) as `tag_id`,
  GROUP_CONCAT( tags.`tag` ORDER BY tags.`id` ASC SEPARATOR ',' ) as `tag_name`
FROM `library` AS library
LEFT JOIN `library_tags` AS libtags
ON library.`id` = libtags.`file` 
LEFT JOIN `tags` AS tags
ON libtags.`tag` = tags.`id` 
AND tags.`id` IN (9,14) 
WHERE library.`app` = "53bd8997ad2ee"
GROUP BY library.`id` 
ORDER BY  library.`created` DESC
LIMIT 99999 OFFSET 0
```

This filters the attached tags, not the rows returned after the LEFT JOIN has been completed. It should run about the same speed, if not faster, than your first query.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't filter the list by tags anymore and still restrict the GROUP_CONCAT to selected tags.